# How to handle range requests for video/mp4 streaming on server

Tags: java, http, networking, apache-httpcomponents

I'm currently trying to implement ranged requests on my server running Java with Apache HTTPCore with the goal to stream mp4 videos with skipping.

I implemented an asynchronous file entity that serves byte range requests correctly. However, when streaming on a webbrowser, I cannot seek in the video. The expected behavior would be that, when I skip, the current request is wrapped up and a new one is sent for the according byte range. However, the browser keeps using the very first request and will just download more from the most current buffered position, i.e. never actually jumping and thus linearly downloading the entire file linearly.

So, my question is, how do I wrap up that request? For small, limited requests from the browser (e.g. "Range: bytes=100-1000") it works well because it's sent very quickly, for unlimited ones (e.g. "Range: bytes=100-" with file size 10GB, where the entity serves the entire file) the request just doesn't complete. Do I just kill the TCP connection after, say, 50MB? Does the client send an HTTP abort request that I'm not catching? How is this done in general with HTTP?

Edit: I tested using a TCP timeout, which didn't work - the browser reports a network error, so the same socket is to be used throughout.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Okay, so I found out the main problem was me lacking ETag/Last-Modified, Date and Cache-Control headers. Now it works on all browsers. My question remains though, how does a huge HTTP request get stopped/only partially downloaded and then replaced by another request? I found out I'm using HTTP 1.0 - is it just that the TCP connection is closed? I don't get any exceptions to indicate such behavior though.